# Make simple 3 port ethernet switch/Hub

Tags: switches, ethernet, hub

How can I make a simple cheap 3 port Switch?
I have 30 10-base low speed Ethernet devices and I want to connect them together, how can these devices connects together with simple Bus topology?
simplest and cheap way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a passive ethernet hub with anti-parallel diodes](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/building-a-passive-ethernet-hub-with-anti-parallel-diodes)

Comment: 10x 3 port Or 1x 30 port?

Comment: 30 Devices exists

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and cheapest way is to go buy one. The off-the-shelf hardware is so inexpensive these days that there's really no way you're going to create a custom solution that saves either money or effort. Both Amazon and [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100010066%20600052097%20600015751&IsNodeId=1&name=10%2f100Mbps&Order=PRICE) list several Ethernet switches for less than $20.